# Assign variables to save each directories from a folder

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, pathfinding

I want to assign corresponding variables based on the name to save each directory from a folder, including its subfolders, so I can get access to the file in each folder easily. The code created by myself doesn't look concise. Any suggestions?

```
import os

modelFld = r'C:\model'


baseInputFld = [os.path.join(modelFld, x) for x in os.listdir(modelFld) if 'base' in x.lower()][0]

oilWellFld = [os.path.join(baseInputFld, x) for x in os.listdir(baseInputFld) if 'oilwell' in x.lower()][0]
diswaterWellFld = [os.path.join(baseInputFld, x) for x in os.listdir(baseInputFld) if 'waterwell' in x.lower()][0]
quarryFld = [os.path.join(baseInputFld, x) for x in os.listdir(baseInputFld) if 'quar' in x.lower()][0]
linearRefFld = [os.path.join(baseInputFld, x) for x in os.listdir(baseInputFld) if 'linear' in x.lower()][0]
txCountyFld = [os.path.join(baseInputFld, x) for x in os.listdir(baseInputFld) if 'county' in x.lower()][0]
tigerFld = [os.path.join(baseInputFld, x) for x in os.listdir(baseInputFld) if 'tiger' in x.lower()][0]

step1Fld = [os.path.join(modelFld, x) for x in os.listdir(modelFld) if 'step1' in x.lower()][0]
step2Fld = [os.path.join(modelFld, x) for x in os.listdir(modelFld) if 'step2' in x.lower()][0]
step3Fld = [os.path.join(modelFld, x) for x in os.listdir(modelFld) if 'step3' in x.lower()][0]
step4Fld = [os.path.join(modelFld, x) for x in os.listdir(modelFld) if 'step4' in x.lower()][0]
step5Fld = [os.path.join(modelFld, x) for x in os.listdir(modelFld) if 'step5' in x.lower()][0]
step6Fld = [os.path.join(modelFld, x) for x in os.listdir(modelFld) if 'step6' in x.lower()][0]

step1InputFld = [os.path.join(step1Fld, x) for x in os.listdir(step1Fld) if 'input' in x.lower()][0]
step2InputFld = [os.path.join(step2Fld, x) for x in os.listdir(step2Fld) if 'input' in x.lower()][0]
step3InputFld = [os.path.join(step3Fld, x) for x in os.listdir(step3Fld) if 'input' in x.lower()][0]
step4InputFld = [os.path.join(step4Fld, x) for x in os.listdir(step4Fld) if 'input' in x.lower()][0]
step5InputFld = [os.path.join(step5Fld, x) for x in os.listdir(step5Fld) if 'input' in x.lower()][0]
step6InputFld = [os.path.join(step6Fld, x) for x in os.listdir(step6Fld) if 'input' in x.lower()][0]

step1OutputFld = [os.path.join(step1Fld, x) for x in os.listdir(step1Fld) if 'output' in x.lower()][0]
step2OutputFld = [os.path.join(step2Fld, x) for x in os.listdir(step2Fld) if 'output' in x.lower()][0]
step3OutputFld = [os.path.join(step3Fld, x) for x in os.listdir(step3Fld) if 'output' in x.lower()][0]
step4OutputFld = [os.path.join(step4Fld, x) for x in os.listdir(step4Fld) if 'output' in x.lower()][0]
step5OutputFld = [os.path.join(step5Fld, x) for x in os.listdir(step5Fld) if 'output' in x.lower()][0]
step6OutputFld = [os.path.join(step6Fld, x) for x in os.listdir(step6Fld) if 'output' in x.lower()][0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create functions to get rid of your repetitive logic. This is called **DRY** (Don't repeat yourself).

The first task you repeatedly accomplish is getting the first object in a base folder matching some string.

This can be accomplished using this function:

```
def find_in(root, string):
    return next(os.path.join(root, x) for x in os.listdir(root) if string in x.lower())
```

Instead of building the whole list and then taking only the first element, this is a generator and the first element of that generator is returned. This should save a bit of time and memory. To appreciate how much, try running these three commands and see how long they take:

```
>>> next(x**2 for x in xrange(100000000)
>>> next(x**2 for x in range(100000000)
>>> [x**2 for x in range(100000000)][0]
```

(The first one uses `xrange`, which is like `range`, but returns also an object like a generator, whereas the normal `range` returns the full list in Python 2.7.)

---

The second task you accomplish is the same thing as the first, but nested once. You want the first element in a `stepX` folder and then get the first object containing`input` or `output` from that folder.

For this we can use the previous function and define a second function:

```
def find_nested(root, step, direction):
    return find_in(find_in(root, step), direction)
```

After this is done we can save the results in lists, instead of separate variables. Lists are for collections of similar objects.

In addition, there is an official Python style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which you should adhere to. It recommends using `lower_case_with_underscores` instead of `camelCase`. You should also avoid abbreviating variable names. Clear and more readable is better.

**Final code:**

```
import os


def find_in(root, string):
    """
    Returns the first object in the folder `root` which matches `string`.
    Case in-sensitive.
    """
    return next((os.path.join(root, x) for x in os.listdir(root) if string in x.lower()))


def find_nested(root, step, direction):
    """Returns the `direction` object from the `step` folder in `root`."""
    return find_in(find_in(root, step), direction)


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    model_field = r'C:\model'
    root_folder = find_in(model_field, 'base')

    folders = ['oilwell', 'waterwell', 'quar', 'linear', 'county', 'tiger']
    fields = [find_in(root_folder, string) for string in folders]

    steps = ["step%i" % (i + 1) for i in range(6)]
    input_fields = [find_nested(root_folder, step, "input") for step in steps]
    output_fields = [find_nested(root_folder, step, "output") for step in steps]
```

In case not all `stepX` folders actually contain an `input` or `output` file/folder, this will raise a `StopIteration`. To avoid this, you can unwrap the list comprehension into an actual `for` loop and print the missing file:

```
input_fields = []
for step in steps:
    try:
        input_fields.append(find_nested(root_folder, step, "input"))
    except StopIteration:
        print "Folder", step, "has no `input` file."
```

And similar for the `output_fields`.